# Как валидно описать массив обьектов?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Приветсвую, я получаю через Апи некую информацию и хочу через интерфейс описать типы данных но столкнулся с трудностью их описания..
Пример того что я получаю:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/p1F51Lvj3sMopG948F5HsBbl43C.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [28, 12, 14],
      "id": 616037,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Thor: Love and Thunder",
      "overview": "After his retirement is interrupted by Gorr the God Butcher, a galactic killer who seeks the extinction of the gods, Thor enlists the help of King Valkyrie, Korg, and ex-girlfriend Jane Foster, who now inexplicably wields Mjolnir as the Mighty Thor. Together they embark upon a harrowing cosmic adventure to uncover the mystery of the God Butcher’s vengeance and stop him before it’s too late.",
      "popularity": 10993.015,
      "poster_path": "/pIkRyD18kl4FhoCNQuWxWu5cBnM.jpg",
      "release_date": "2022-07-06",
      "title": "Thor: Love and Thunder",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.7,
      "vote_count": 1657
    },
```

Я начал делать вот так :

```
export interface FilmType{
    page: number;
    results: Array<any>{
     
    }

}
```

Если делать через any то суть теряется..

Comment: опиши отдельный тип для элементов массива

Comment: Как-то так ? https://codepen.io/IvaLu/pen/LYdmqYb?editors=0010

Comment: @WebJun Да, только `popularity` - `number`, а не `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export interface FilmPage { // лучше описать как FilmPage, потому что это не фильм, а страница с фильмами
    page: number;
    results: Film[]; // интерфейс для фильмов вынести отдельно
}

export interface Film { // А это уже Film, использовать FilmType не стоит, потому что это интерфейс, а не тип (может ввести в заблуждение)
    adult: boolean;
    backdrop_path: string;
    genre_ids: number[];
    id: number;
    original_language: string; // лучше такие вещи вынести в enum, чтобы не ошибиться в написании.
    original_title: string;
    overview: string;
    popularity: number;
    poster_path: string;
    release_date: string; // тут может быть еще Date, в зависимости от формата данных
    title: string;
    video: boolean;
    vote_average: number;
    vote_count: number;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, переделаю